# How to add multiple items from an array to another array

Tags: javascript, arrays

I have got code like this:

```
arr1 = [1,2,3];
arr2 = [4,5,6];
```

I want to add array 2 to array 1 so arr1 will equal `[1,2,3,4,5,6]`.

I have tried `arr1.push(arr2)`, but that returns `[1,2,3,[4,5,6]]`.

Comment: `.concat()` instead of `.push()` should work (`.concat` will return a new array rather than changing it place though)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Two quick and easy ways are two use [Array.concat](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/concat) or the [spread](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Spread_syntax) operator.

```js
const arr1 = [1,2,3];
const arr2 = [4,5,6];

// With concat
console.log(arr1.concat(arr2));

// With spread
console.log([...arr1, ...arr2])
```